# YAML_CPP issue using XCode: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: yaml-cpp

When I build 'SuperCollider' on MacOS 12.5.1 using using XCode and -'std=gnu++17' using it's internal 'yaml-cpp' I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "YAML::BadConversion::~BadConversion()", referenced from:
      YAML::TypedBadConversion<bool>::~TypedBadConversion() in libsclang.a(SC_LanguageConfig.o)
      YAML::TypedBadConversion<bool>::~TypedBadConversion() in libsclang.a(SC_LanguageConfig.o)
      YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::~TypedBadConversion() in libsclang.a(PyrStringPrim.o)
      YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >::~TypedBadConversion() in libsclang.a(PyrStringPrim.o)
  "YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_map(std::__1::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder> const&)", referenced from:
      YAML::detail::node& YAML::detail::node_data::get<char const*>(char const* const&, std::__1::shared_ptr<YAML::detail::memory_holder>) in libsclang.a(SC_LanguageConfig.o)
  "typeinfo for YAML::BadConversion", referenced from:
      typeinfo for YAML::TypedBadConversion<bool> in libsclang.a(SC_LanguageConfig.o)
      typeinfo for YAML::TypedBadConversion<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > > in libsclang.a(PyrStringPrim.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **
 % nm ../lang/SuperCollider.build/RelWithDebInfo/libsclang.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SC_LanguageConfig.o | grep Conversion

                 U __ZN4YAML13BadConversionD2Ev
0000000000004620 T __ZN4YAML18TypedBadConversionIbED0Ev
0000000000004610 T __ZN4YAML18TypedBadConversionIbED1Ev
                 U __ZTIN4YAML13BadConversionE
0000000000006658 S __ZTIN4YAML18TypedBadConversionIbEE
0000000000006e0e S __ZTSN4YAML18TypedBadConversionIbEE
0000000000006670 S __ZTVN4YAML18TypedBadConversionIbEE
```

When I build 'SuperCollider' using the system's yaml-cpp (from Macports) it builds properly.

When I build the 'yaml_cpp' project which is using '-std=gnu++11', it works:

https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp

```
 % nm ./RelWithDebInfo/libyaml-cpp.0.7.0.dylib | grep Conversion        
00000000000117e0 T __ZN4YAML13BadConversionD0Ev
00000000000117b0 T __ZN4YAML13BadConversionD1Ev
0000000000011780 T __ZN4YAML13BadConversionD2Ev
00000000000308f8 S __ZTIN4YAML13BadConversionE
000000000002ea19 S __ZTSN4YAML13BadConversionE
00000000000308d0 S __ZTVN4YAML13BadConversionE
```

There's are differences in exceptions.h, and no 'exceptions.cpp' in SuperCollider/external_libraries, instead, it has 'exceptions.hpp':

```
% diff include/yaml-cpp ~/SuperCollider/external_libraries/yaml-cpp/include/yaml-cpp/ |  grep Conversion
< class YAML_CPP_API BadConversion : public RepresentationException {
> class BadConversion : public RepresentationException {
<   BadConversion(const BadConversion&) = default;
<   ~BadConversion() YAML_CPP_NOEXCEPT override;
```

Is there an issue building projects with 'yaml-cpp' with '-std=gnu++17'?
Some other issue? (E.g. - 'SuperCollider' included the wrong version of 'yaml-cpp'?